# Permission denied when using ActiveX DeleteFile

Tags: javascript, windows, activex, wsh

I have a script that's working wonderfully until it tries to delete the temporary files it creates, then I get a Permission Denied error message.

The command is simply:

```
fso.DeleteFile(tempWAVPath)
```

Where `fso` is `ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` and `tempWAVPath` is: `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\RandomTempName\TemporaryFile`

Considering the script created both the folder and the file, I'm perplexed as to why it's getting a Permission denied error.

The script is being run via an Admin CMD and `cscript`

Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! The file was ReadOnly. Fixed it by adding the following:

```
file = fso.GetFile(tempWAVPath)
if(file.attributes & 1) {
    file.attributes = file.attributes - 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle read-only files is to pass a second Boolean argument as follows:

```
fso.DeleteFile(tempWAVPath, true);
```

Comment: Command in specific case still fails for me. Seems like there may be a file lock of some sort - any way to check/clear it?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the other answers were successful for me on a particular file.

This however did work 100%:

```
file = fso.GetFile(FILE_PATH);
file.Delete(true);
```